# Finding where something was imported from in python

Tags: python

In a django project sometimes you have code like

```
from settings import *
```

or

```
from local_settings import *
```

Then in the rest of your code you do things like

```
from django.conf import settings
```

What I'm wanting to do is find out how to know which part of settings came from which file.  I'm guessing I have to hook the import module somehow and maybe keep track of 'settings' before and after the import.

Not even really sure where to start with something like this.  I know about `__file__`, but that won't work here since I'm looking for where each variable in the settings module comes from.

---

More information

I've written a django app I want to open source that will show you your composite settings.  But before I released it, I wanted to add the ability to see where your individual settings are coming from.  Similar to the "Matched CSS Rules" in Chrome devtools.

Some of my projects import as many as 4 files, one base.py, one customer.py one sub-customer.py and then a machine.py.  Figuring out where the setting is coming from can be interesting at times.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Are you running in an IDE, or just a text editor?

Comment: Do you really think this will add value? Consider the scenario where settings are loaded from the environment; how will you account for that? Or how about if someone just sets `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.foo`.  Why is it necessary to know where the settings are coming from?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Because I have projects that are deployed onto multiple companies computers, some on windows, some on linux, some in apache, some in nginx.  This is a problem I already have, and while I have a partial solution, I want to provide additional information to make my life easier.  It already does deal with the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODLUE=`, but my settings files can be composed of up to 4 separate files.  Just the nature of SAAS running on the customers computers vs one monolithic install.

Comment: What is the _problem_? You can already compare your settings against the django defaults with [`diffsettings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-diffsettings), and you can also [provide your own defaults](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/settings/#custom-default-settings); so I am not sure why does it matter were the variable was set?

Answer (score 3):

There's no import provenance for ordinary values.

The solution is not to use the `from <module> import *` directive; instead import the module and refer to its members directly.

Another practical solution for your use case is to use an ide which can show you what is defined in each file, and use that to help you analyse the source of a given setting.

A programmatic solution (assuming each settings file does not import the other) is to import one file, make a copy of its `__dict__`, and then import the next one. You can then compare them for changes, then repeat with the next import.

Comment: Not sure how to avoid this in a django project when dealing with the settings.  Settings are imported as a module and if you need local settings to override global settings, there isn't any other way that I have found.  http://django-configurations.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ is one possibility, but I haven't had a chance to try and implement it, and quite frankly it looks like as much trouble as import * a the moment.

Comment: @Mark0978 Well, in that case, it should be easy: if the setting isn't set in the local file, it must be set in the global file.

Comment: @Mark0978 So, you have 4 levels of searching. I don't think this makes it conceptually any harder. You might like to use an IDE with a code explorer to see what's in each file.

Comment: I think honestly this is a solution looking for a problem; especially since the OP isn't talking about an IDE, but rather a feature in a module he is thinking of releasing.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I would say the same of the entire question. Hence why I think using an IDE of some sort is the real solution, to the extent there is a real problem.

Comment: @Marcin Believe what you will.  It's a problem I already have, and one I have a partial solution to.  I currently have have 8 different customers (with 2 pending) giving me a total of nearly 32 files, going to 40.  If you only ever deploy your software to one machine, or if all your deployments are 100% identical, then yes, it is a solution in search of a problem, but banks don't want to outsource storage of financial information, they want our solution deployed in their shop.   And each of them has a different version of SAML, email addresses....

Comment: @Mark0978 It sounds like you're complaining about me providing you with a solution. Or is your complaint that my solution doesn't mesh with yours? That's because you say nothing about what you have done to solve the problem.

Comment: @Marcin Each of the files imports the other files, so this won't work.  Basically the machine file imports the sub-company which imports the company which imports the base.  I have something which is similar to diffsettings (with optionally less verbose output), but I was trying to find a way to know where each variable of settings came from.  Searching files in an IDE isn't a pleasant solution, I'd like to dump the setting and it value and the file it came from.  Nothing I see in your responses gives me any more of a solution than I had before I posted the question.

Comment: @Mark0978 Well, we are all coming to this cold *because you have not given any details of your solution*. However, the `__dict__` trick will work just fine if you stop having the files import each other, and instead have one file which imports all of the others. Alternatively, you could strip off the imports programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

Classes, functions and a couple of other objects have a `__module__` attribute. You can get the module object from `sys.modules`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.utime.__module__
'posix'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules[os.utime.__module__]
<module 'posix' (built-in)>
```

PS: I recommend that you follow Marcin's advice and avoid star imports.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use `*` imports:

```
from base import *
from customer import *
from subcustomer import *
from machine import *
```

you can still import the module itself:

```
import base
import customer
import subcustomer
import machine
```

and get some idea of what variables have been added to the global namespace by each of the modules:

```
base_names = set(dir(base))
customer_names = set(dir(customer))
subcustomer_names = set(dir(subcustomer))
machine_names = set(dir(machine))
common = base_names & customer_names & subcustomer_names & machine_names
```

I'm not sure how you will wish to handle variable names that have been defined in more than one module. But you could find those names definitely defined by a particular module by using set subtraction. For example, to find names definitely defined by the `base` module you could compute:

```
base_names - customer_names - subcustomer_names - machine_names
```

Comment: You might be on to something here.  Awesome, I'll see if I can work that in.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at the inspect module. 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html ?
you can look at the entire stack of calls.

but really, what are you trying to solve ?